# Why is there an error parsing the returned XML signature?

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

Ensure that the SecurityTokenResolver is populated with the required key.

```
ID4037: The key needed to verify the signature could not be resolved from the following security key identifier 'SecurityKeyIdentifier
(
IsReadOnly = False,
Count = 1,
Clause[0] = System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2SecurityKeyIdentifierClause
)
```

Comment: I'm in doubt about the cause of this error. Please add a stack trace.